# How can I change all of my section titles formatting in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, titles

I am looking to change all of my titles to look like the ones below (created in word), does anybody know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: The answer will depend on the class you are going to use.

Comment: I am using \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, fleqn]{article}

Comment: Also, while possible, it is a bad idea to underline section titles. Underlining is nothing LaTeX is particularly good at and it has some serious limitations. Do you use LuaLaTeX? In that engine underlining is better supported. Also underlining is generally considered one of the bad forms of highlighting in typography.

Comment: I haven't heard of LuaLaTeX before, I am creating a document for my university notes and LaTeX is one of the best ways to typeset mathematics (otherwise I'd use Word normally). The underlining is so that when I skim through my notes it is easier to distinguish between topics.

Comment: Look into the `sectsty` or `titlesec` packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\centering\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\underline}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\color{darkgray}}{}{0pt}{\underline}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\color{gray}}{}{0pt}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Title}
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you :)